# jQuery .on() event map for multiple selectors

Tags: jquery, delegates

I've read through a few posts for event delegation using jQuery's .on() method, but none of them have shown if there's a way to bind different maps to different selectors in the same method. 
This works for example:

```
$(document) 
.on("click", ".someSelector", function(){...})
.on("click", ".someOtherSelector", function(){...})
```

But ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$(document).on({
"click": someFunction,
"change": somethingElse
}, .selector1,{
"click": function(){...},
"change": function(){...}
}, .selector2);
```

Is this or something similar possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing! Looks to me like you just gotta [stack](https://jsfiddle.net/unitof/3dszoheu/) a few `.on()` methods on top of each other.

```
$(document).on({
    "click": function() {...},
    "change": function() {...}
}, ".selector1").on({
    "click": function() {...},
    "change": function() {...}
}, ".selector2");
```